# Access denied for 'user'@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

I'm trying to create model using phalcon. But when I type `phalcon model polls` I get an error as `ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`.

I can get into mysql using `mysql -p`. So I tried to create new user and grant him all privileges, but it didn't help. I also can login into phpmyadmin using root and password. I also tried to specify the port as 3306 in config file, but still nothing.

My config file:

```
defined('BASE_PATH') || define('BASE_PATH', getenv('BASE_PATH') ?: realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../..'));
defined('APP_PATH') || define('APP_PATH', BASE_PATH . '/app');

return new \Phalcon\Config([
    'database' => [
        'adapter' => 'Mysql',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => 3306,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '$Pass1234 ',
        'dbname' => 'poll_db',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
    'application' => [
        'appDir' => APP_PATH . '/',
        'controllersDir' => APP_PATH . '/controllers/',
        'modelsDir' => APP_PATH . '/models/',
        'migrationsDir' => APP_PATH . '/migrations/',
        'viewsDir' => APP_PATH . '/views/',
        'pluginsDir' => APP_PATH . '/plugins/',
        'libraryDir' => APP_PATH . '/library/',
        'cacheDir' => BASE_PATH . '/cache/',

        // This allows the baseUri to be understand project paths that are not in the root directory
        // of the webpspace.  This will break if the public/index.php entry point is moved or
        // possibly if the web server rewrite rules are changed. This can also be set to a static path.
        'baseUri' => preg_replace('/public([\/\\\\])index.php$/', '', $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]),
    ]
]);
```

P.S I did all operation about granting privileges entering to mysql by `mysql -u root -p`

P.P.S I also did `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` and then restarted mysql, but nothing. Thanks for future help.

UPD: I also tried to created project in laravel, and made migration and everything works fine. I also used root + password.

SOLVED: I don't know why, but I decided to create new project, and everything worked fine even with 'root'@'localhost'. Seems like something wrong was with first project. Even so, thank for all people who participated in helping.

P.S I marked [EternHour's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3824283/eternalhour) answer as solution just for people who might get same error in future.

Comment: How do you register your database service in the DI container?

Comment: @NikolaosDimopoulos I didn't do anything like registering services in DI container, I'm completely new in phalcon.

Comment: Are you connecting the MySQL server in Laravel with socket or with tcp connection?

Comment: @KoalaYeung I'm not sure, I create project using composer create-project, and then hust modify .env file

Comment: Did you have `DB_PORT` in your Laravel's `.env` file?

Comment: @KoalaYeung yes, i have DB_PORT = 3306, with laravel everything works fine. The problem is in phalcon or DB

Comment: You should have `'port' => 3306` in your Phalcon config. If you tried that and failed, please also check other part of the config to see if there is any typo (cause more than often that is the issue).

Comment: @KoalaYeung I added port, but still nothing, I updated config file description, please take a look

Comment: i think this is privilege issue and you need to [grant privilage](https://kyup.com/tutorials/create-new-user-grant-permissions-mysql/) to your user.

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde I created new user, following your tutorial, I changed config file wuth new creentials, but still nothing

Comment: What host is running PHP+Phalcon? Are you running everything locally or are you using Docker / Vagrant / etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a port issue, the request is reaching it's destination. Using `root@localhost` will work when logging in through the command line (`mysql -u root -p`) but you don't want to use it for connecting with your code. Keep in mind that when establishing your connection, you need to use `host=localhost` or `host=127.0.0.1` explicitly. If you use the IP address (even on the same server), you will get access denied.

```
[user@localhost ~]# mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --protocol=TCP -u root -p
Enter password:
mysql>
[user@localhost ~]# mysql --host=192.168.1.10 --protocol=TCP -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'hostname' (using password: YES)
```

**Here are the steps I'd recommend taking:**

1. Create a dedicated user that you can use for connecting in your scripts.
2. If source of script is same server as MySQL.

   ```
   CREATE USER '<user>'@'localhost'
   IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
   GRANT ALL
   ON <database>.*
   TO '<user>'@'localhost';
   ```
3. If the connection is always established from the same place but a different location than MySQL, run the following on the command line.

   ```
   CREATE USER '<user>'@'<IP_address>'
   IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
   GRANT ALL
   ON <database>.*
   TO '<user>'@'<IP_address>';
   ```
4. If the source of the connection varies, run the following command.

   ```
   CREATE USER '<user>'@'<IP_address>'
   IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
   GRANT ALL
   ON <database>.*
   TO '<user>'@'%';
   ```

Here is a link to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-accounts.html) if you have any questions.

Comment: _"you don't want to use it for connecting with your code"_  true but it _should_ work

Comment: If OP is connecting via TCP (in their code), I don't believe it will. Unless root has the `'root'@'%'` privilege which doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: I always thought the default for `localhost` was to (attempt to) use the socket. Typically if you want to enforce TCP, you use `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Gonna test some different scenarios. For example, if they are in fact using localhost to make the connection that would probably work. But if they are using an IP address (other than 127.0.0.1) I don't think it will.

Comment: Idk why, but I created new proect, and eeverything started working fine, with all users I created including the root.

Comment: Well that's good. Must have been something you were overlooking :)